# CountdownTimer pause and resume functions

Tags: android, countdown, countdowntimer

I created a countdown timer based on a tutorial I search in Google. But I was unable to resume on the countdown. It will restarted again from 10 when I pressed on the button.

I want to create a countdown timer that are able to pause and resume. Thanks! Here's my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TimerC extends Activity {
Button btns;
    TextView tv;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer_c);

    btns = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnstartpause);
    tv  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    tv.setText("10"); 
    btns.setText("Start");

    final MyCounter timer = new MyCounter(10000,1000);

  btns.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (btns.getText()== "Start")
            {
                timer.start();  

                btns.setText("Pause");
            }
            else if (btns.getText()== "Pause")
            {
                btns.setText("Start");
                timer.cancel();                 
            }
        }
    });    
}

public class MyCounter extends CountDownTimer{

    public MyCounter(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        System.out.println("Timer Completed.");
        tv.setText("Timer Completed.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        tv.setText((millisUntilFinished/1000)+"");
        System.out.println("Timer  : " + (millisUntilFinished/1000));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I declared one integer and named it as _remain_, then I saved the remaining number into the _remain_ when the button is clicked. When clicked to resume, I put back the _remain_ using `setText`. Well, it's not working. The result was still the same as the code above. Thanks.

Comment: In this post I provide a easy solution for this problem, using a CustomCountDownTimer Class which allow you to pause and resume freely. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36965624/pause-resume-countdowntimer-android/36965625#36965625

Hope that it will help you!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem should be the string comparison here:

```
 btns.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (btns.getText()== "Start")
        {
            timer.start();  

            btns.setText("Pause");
        }
        else if (btns.getText()== "Pause")
        {
            btns.setText("Start");
            timer.cancel();                 
        }
    }
});
```

You should use object.equals(otherObject) because == operator compares the referances not the values. example:

```
 btns.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (btns.getText().equals("Start"))
        {
            timer.start();  

            btns.setText("Pause");
        }
        else if (btns.getText().equals("Pause"))
        {
            btns.setText("Start");
            timer.cancel();                 
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep the value of `millisUntilFinished` time in `onTick` in a class attribute. And when you want to restart the timer, re-instantiate it with this value as the first parameter like this :
**Edit :** 
Set timer as a class attribute :

```
private MyCounter timer;
```

And change the listener to this :

```
btns.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (btns.getText().equals("Start"))
        {
            timer = new MyCounter(remainingTime, 1000);
            timer.start();  

            btns.setText("Pause");
        }
        else if (btns.getText().equals("Pause"))
        {
            btns.setText("Start");
            timer.cancel();                 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I keep the value using `long remaining = millisUntilFinished;` and put under `public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {`. How can I re-instantiate as the first parameter? New here, thanks!